# Render to Texture in opengl

Tags: opengl

I get ERROR : GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MISSING_ATTACHMENT with the following code. Any ideas on what I might be missing here:

```
glGenTextures(1, &tex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA4, 640, 480, 0, GL_RGBA4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

glGenFramebuffers(1, &renderTexture);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, renderTexture);
//glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex, 0);
glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, tex, 0);
glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);


GLint val = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);

if(val != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
{
    std::cout <<"\n Error in framebuffer  : 2";
}
```

Here's rest of the code for rendering and blit to default FB.But doesnt render anything any ideas? Expecting a green clear on the default FB

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glClearColor(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);


glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, renderTexture);
glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0); 
val = glGetError();
if( val == GL_NO_ERROR)
    std::cout<<"\n Bind  Fine";

val = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
if(val != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
{
    std::cout <<"\n Error in framebuffer  : 3";
}   
glBlitFramebuffer(0,0,128,128,0,0,128,128, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);
```

Comment: Wrong order of calls. You need to call `glBindFramebuffer()` before `glFramebufferTexture2D()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to bind the FBO before making calls that operate on it. OpenGL calls that modify objects generally operate on a currently bound object. It's the same scheme you follow with the texture at the start of the posted code, where you generate a texture id with `glGenTextures()`, bind it with `glBindTexture()`, and then make calls that modify the texture, like `glTexParameteri()` and `glTexImage2D()`.

In the FBO case, `glFrameBufferTexture2D()` and `glDrawBuffer()` operate on the currently bound FBO. So the `glBindFramebuffer()` call needs to be before those calls:

```
glGenFramebuffers(...);
glBindFramebuffer(...);
glFramebufferTexture2D(...);
glDrawBuffer(...);
```

It's always a good idea to call `glGetError()` if you see any unexpected behavior with your code. You would have seen a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error from the `glFramebufferTexture2D()` call because no FBO was bound.

A couple more observations on the code:

- The `glDrawBuffer()` call is redundant in this case. `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` is the default draw buffer for FBOs.
- While you can use `glFramebufferTexture()` here, `glFramebufferTexture2D()` will work just as well. `glFramebufferTexture()` requires a newer OpenGL version (3.2), and is only beneficial for layered attachments (texture arrays, etc.).

Comment: I have updated the code to render to texture and then Blit to default FB , but nothing gets rendered. Its all black.
Any ideas?